# Virtual Methods and Multiple Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Maybe it is a very basic question but my object orientation experience come form Java, thats why I am not sure about this one.

```
class A
   |
class B
   |
class C
```

I have `class A` which has `A::doSmth()` as a `virtual protected` method. My `class B` inherit from `class A` and re-implement `doSmth()` as a `private` method. Now I want to create `class C` and I want to modify `doSmth()` method for this class. I guess I need to make `doSmth()` method in `class B` virtual, yes? Or since `class B` inherit from `class A` and `doSmth()` is virtual in there, I can simpley modify it in `class C` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to make doSmth() method in class B virtual, yes?

No, you are not required to do this if it is already declared `virtual` in class `A`. `doSmth()` will be virtual in all types derived from `A`. It might help to make the code more readable if you declare it `virtual` in each derived type that overrides it though.

Answer (score 0):

No, in C++ if you declare a particular function as a virtual it **becomes virtual through out derived classes**. However adding virtual in derived classes improves readability and understanding so its a good practice